# Fluids - Physical Interpretation of Stress Tensor Terms

Tags: fluid-dynamics, stress-strain

In a viscous fluid, $σ_{ij}$ denotes a force per unit area in the direction $i$, on a surface with a normal pointing in the $j$ direction. So $i=j$ describes pressure forces and $i\neq j$ is for tangential/shear forces.

[image]

Viscous forces arise due to friction so occur only when different parts of the fluid have different velocities. So $σ_{ij}$ should depend on the velocity gradients. If the velocity of the fluid varies over a much larger scale than the mean free path (or some characteristic interaction length in the case of a liquid) of the particles then we can suppose that $σ_{ij}$ depends only on first derivatives of velocity. Lastly, if we assume the fluid is Newtonian and so the dependence is linear, the most general form for the stress tensor we can write down would be:

$$σ_{ij}\propto\frac{∂v_i}{∂x_j}+A\frac{∂v_j}{∂x_i}+B\delta_{ij}\frac{∂v_j}{∂x_k}$$

where $A$ and $B$ are constants to be determined, and the Kronecker delta term on the RHS is there so we can treat the trace independently. To work out the constant $A$, consider the following simple case:

A flow is rotating anticlockwise with angular velocity $Ω$ in the x-y plane, meaning that $σ_{xy}=0$ (there is no stress if it's 'rigidly' rotating).

[image]

Writing $v_x=-yΩ$ and $v_y=xΩ$, we can then see:
$$σ_{xy}\propto\frac{∂v_x}{∂y}+A\frac{∂v_y}{∂x}= -Ω+AΩ  \stackrel{!}{=}0$$
so $A = 1$.

The term $\frac{∂v_x}{∂y}$, by itself, gives a tangential stress because there is a net transport of momentum in the $x$ direction along $y$, which arises from the random motion of the molecules*. This gives a rate of change of momentum $\equiv$ a force, in the x-direction, acting on a surface with normal in the y-direction.

This tangential stress is exactly cancelled by the $\frac{∂v_y}{∂x}$ term, so that $σ_{xy} = 0$.

**My confusion is that** I can't see *physically* how a gradient in $v_y$ could ever produce a force in the $x$-direction, to cancel out this first force. I would've thought a gradient in $v_y$ can only produce a rate of change of momentum in the $y$ direction.

*see e.g. section 2.1.3, page 28, https://www.physics.ox.ac.uk/system/files/file_attachments/notes.pdf